# Why is my laptop so hot suddenly?

Tags: 13.04, overheating

After an update my laptop is extremely hot. Normally I let it run for a couple of days without a single problem, but suddenly it is starting to feel very hot, and the fan is blowing like hell, but I didn’t do anything weird

Comment: laptop specs ?.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there unexpected CPU usage? Whenever my system heats up, I open a terminal, run `top`, and press P to sort by CPU usage. Usually there's a process or two near the top using up more processor time than they should, and depending on which process it is, I either close that window or paste the name into a search engine to see if it corresponds to known performance issues in Ubuntu (e.g. pulseaudio, tracker, xapian, etc.).